# How to add list to a new created page

Tags: publishing-site

I am adding a new publishing page in c#, how can I add listview webpart to this specific page now?

```
      PublishingPage page = null;
      page = publishingPageCollection.Add("NewPage1" + ".aspx", pageLayout);
      page.Title = "NewPage1";
      page.Update();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below code , i have used it on feature activated . You can call this method after the page is successfully created and checked-in. Also check the below link 
http://moresharepoints.blogspot.com/2012/04/adding-webpart-to-page-programatically.html

```
public override void 
FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
{
SPSite site = properties.Feature.Parent as SPSite;
using(SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
{
    using(SPLimitedWebPartManager wpManager = web.GetLimitedWebPartManager(page url, System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.Shared))
    {
        YourWebPart webpart = new YourWebPart();
        webpart.ZoneID = "Top";
        webpart.Title = "My Webpart";
        wpManager.AddWebPart(webpart,"Top" , 0);
    }
}
```

}